# How to fix "Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root" error?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, jax-ws

I'am continue =)) to create jax-ws soap web service on Tomcat 7 using Eclipse (with varied success).

I have interface in my Eclipse "mavened" webapp project:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://new.webservice.namespace", name = "MayaServiceInterface")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface MayaServiceInterface {


    @WebResult(name = "getPersonResponse", targetNamespace = "http://new.webservice.namespace", partName = "parameter")
    public getPersonResponse getCustomer(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameter", name = "getPersonRequest", targetNamespace = "http://new.webservice.namespace")
        getPersonRequest parameter

    );

}
```

and class which implements interface:

```
@javax.jws.WebService
     (
                      serviceName = "ABCWsService",
                      portName = "ABCWsPort",
                      targetNamespace = "http://new.webservice.namespace",
                      endpointInterface = "com.mayacomp.ws.MayaServiceInterface")


public class MayaServiceEndPoindImpl implements MayaServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public getPersonResponse getCustomer(getPersonRequest parameter) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


} // end of class
```

when I am trying to "run on Server" web service i receive a page with next info:

> Web Services Endpoint  Information   Service Name:
>   {http://new.webservice.namespace}ABCWsService  Port Name:
>   {http://new.webservice.namespace}ABCWsPort    Address:
>   http://localhost:8080/maya-web-service/ABCWs  WSDL:
>   http://localhost:8080/maya-web-service/ABCWs?wsdl  Implementation
>   class: com.mayacomp.ws.MayaServiceEndPoindImpl

when I click on http://localhost:8080/maya-web-service/ABCWs?wsdl i receive HTTP 500 error and next info in the eclipse console:

> may 05, 2015 7:08:16 PM
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet SEVERE:
>   caught throwable java.io.IOException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT
>   when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.SDDocumentImpl.writeTo(SDDocumentImpl.java:299)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.publishWSDL(HttpAdapter.java:931)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handleGet(HttpAdapter.java:440)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:161)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doGet(WSServlet.java:89)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when
>   document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).   at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.throwOutputError(BaseStreamWriter.java:1518)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.reportNwfStructure(BaseStreamWriter.java:1547)
>     at
>   com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter._finishDocument(BaseStreamWriter.java:1373)
>     at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.close(BaseStreamWriter.java:243)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XMLStreamWriterFilter.close(XMLStreamWriterFilter.java:67)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.SDDocumentImpl.writeTo(SDDocumentImpl.java:297)
>     ... 27 more

But i'am waiting to receive wsdl (If this does not sound strange). Please, help me to fix this error and view my wsdl.

Comment: I add objects instead of return null but it does not solve the problem. =(( Also I added path to wsdl (wsdlLocation) into @javax.jws.WebService annotation.

Comment: The problem was in Tomcat preferences in Eclipse. I deployed war directrly to Tomcat and it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about stax-ex jar.

- you can put stax-ex-1.7.7.jar to your library location
- you can add 

      org.jvnet.staxex
      stax-ex
      1.7.7

to your pom.xml